# awk getting good distribution of random integer values between 2 inputs

Tags: awk

How to get a good distribution of random integer values between 2 inputs using awk?.

I'm trying the below

```
$ awk -v min=200 -v max=500 ' BEGIN { srand();for(i=0;i<10;i++) print int(min+rand()*100*(max/min))  } '
407
406
360
334
264
365
303
417
249
225
$
```

Is there a better way in awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to inform you that your code is not even correct.  Try with min=max=10.

Something like this will work.  You can verify the uniformity as well.

```
$ awk -v min=200 -v max=210 ' BEGIN{srand();
                                    for(i=0;i<10000;i++) a[int(min+rand()*(max-min))]++; 
                                    for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' | sort
200 1045
201 966
202 1014
203 1016
204 985
205 1010
206 988
207 1027
208 986
209 963
```

Note also that min is inclusive but max is not.